# Undefined variable: data on datepicker

Tags: php, sql-server, codeigniter, model-view-controller, datepicker

I am trying to get the date as varchar from the datepicker to fetch data from my SQL database and show results from the table, but my variable doesn't recognize using this code. My error is "Undefined variable: data"

I am using MVC as my framework and MsSql for my db.

**Model**

```
function srch_ecms()
{

$x = explode('.',$data['fromDate']);

//print_r ($data);

$qString = "";
$qString .= '[dbo].[SEARCH_ecms] '; //STORED PROCEDURE
$qString .= "'" .$data['fromDate']."'";
//echo $qString;
$query = $this->db->query($qString);
print_r($query->result());
return ($query->num_rows() > 0 ? $query->result() : NULL);

}
```

**View**

```
  <form method="post" action="<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/welcome/search_ecms">
<p>Select Date
</br>
From: <input  type="text" name="fromDate" id="fromDate" /> To: <input type="text" name="toDate" id="toDate" /></p>

<input type="submit" value="Submit" name="dateData" id="dateData"/>
</form>
```

**Controller**

```
function search_ecms() {
    $data['dateData']=$this->input->post('dateData');
    $this->load->model('navi_model');
    $query = $this->navi_model->srch_ecms();
    $data['ecms'] = $query;

}
```

**Stored Procedure**

```
    @fileDate VARCHAR(20)

AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
        declare @tablesuffix varchar(10)
        select @tablesuffix=upper(substring(datename(m,convert(datetime,@fileDate)),1,3))+convert(varchar,year(convert(datetime,@fileDate)))
    print @tablesuffix
    DECLARE @sqlCommand varchar(1000)
    SET @sqlCommand = 'SELECT gen_048_' + @tablesuffix 
    EXEC (@sqlCommand)

END
```

Comment: Where is the load view for it. I do not see it in controller

Comment: where did `$data` inside model method `srch_ecms` came from? it's not supplied as an agument

Comment: oh yah, you mean this? `$data['dateData']=$this->input->post('dateData');` ? I already edited the code.